# What Star Wars canon works relate to the time period between Return of the Jedi and The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, canon, return-of-the-jedi

Back in the pre-Disney days, there was a wealth of canon works of various stripes that dealt with the Star Wars galaxy after the events of Return of the Jedi. From the Dark Forces / Jedi Knight / Jedi Academy games to the books (I had a personal preference for the X-Wing series).

Since the relegation of all of this to Legends status, what works remain in canon to cover the time period between Return of the Jedi and The Force Awakens?

I am aware of [*Aftermath*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath) (which is somewhere on my future reading list). I'd be specifically interested in any that deal with the development of the New Republic.

Comment: @WadCheber While the answer you're linking me to does indeed list all canon works, it doesn't place them in the timeline: so it doesn't really address the question I am asking. It's also from January last year (although I can see it's been edited recently) so I can't know how complete it is.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - You'll be pleased to hear that while the original answer was posted in Jan 2015, it was last updated only a few days ago. It contains a link to the "[Journey to the Force Awakens](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Journey_to_Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens)" page on Wookieepedia as well as listing the most recent Marvel comic serials and the new short stories found in Star Wars Insider.

Comment: I retracted my vote to close and posted an answer.  I'm not sure it's not a duplicate, but I will give it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen this, and then vote to close it as a "list of works" question.

Comment: @Valorum I wonder if you should put a header at the top of that answer to say that it's being kept up-to-date and mention the last time you edited it. This isn't the first time somebody has thought it outdated because of when it was posted.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I did consider it, but then it would be the only post on the site with such a header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:  This information was probably outdated and incomplete 5 minutes after I posted it*

As far as the Del Rey Novel timeline is concerned, we have this, from *Star Wars:  Bloodline*, published in May 2016:

[image]

Expanding the scope to include all media, we have [this infographic](http://www.outerplaces.com/star-wars-timeline/) produced by Outer Places in November 2015:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And for good measure, Comics Alliance's own December 2015 infographic:

[image]

Comment: Battlefront isn't canon (well, [bits of it are](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2015/04/29/star-wars-battlefront-canon-is-complicated), maybe)